# Where is the voltage drop? / How can I test circuit this without using an actual battery?

Tags: mosfet, lithium-ion

I've put together the following circuit, it's just a rechargable LED torch, just to try load sharing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS7YqV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BAT1 is a LiPo battery, 5.2 V comes from the AC adapter when the thing is being charged. There's a charging circuit connected, but I'm using a module, so I couldn't include that in the schematic, but I think it should be irrelevant as the battery is basically disconnected in this configuration.

The voltage drop on D1 was around 0.2 V, but the voltage between V1 and ground was around 3.9. The battery was at 3.7-3.8 V at the time, but like I said, it should be irrelevant.

- What am I missing? Where could that additional 1 V voltage drop come from?
- Is my battery safe, and completely disconnected from the load?
- Can you recommend a test setup so I can check this without actually using a LiPo battery?

It is entirely possible that I've messed up assembling the circuit, I'll probably build another later anyway.

Comment: If the volt drop on D1 was 0.2 volts and V1 is 3.9 volts then your DC supply voltage can only be 4.1 volts.

Comment: Are you sure the FET source and gate are correctly identified. If they were swapped the supply may charge the battery via D1 and FET body diode.- What is the supply voltage AT the supply?

Comment: @Andyaka That's what I thought, for that I want to make another circuit and have a test setup (without a LiPo), but I don't exactly know how to do that.

Comment: So, measure the total voltage and prove 5.2 volts IS 5.2 volts.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Now that you mention it, I've had failed test runs because I've set up the FET incorrectly twice (mostly because I wasn't paying enough attention). It's not impossible, that I have semi-fried the FET with that or the multiple soldering/desoldering.

Comment: @Andyaka I will make another clean circuit and measure that, because based on the other question I've realized there were too many things going wrong with this one. I've rephrased the question to emphasize I'm asking for test setup suggestions as well.

Comment: @Wrock I'd suggest to delete this question and ask setup suggestions in a new question (as this question's content is distracting)

Comment: No, don't do that. Since this question doesn't have any answers yet, go ahead and edit it as needed. Don't create a duplicate question.

Comment: Note that you CAN emulate a LiPo - but there is no guarantee you are doing so here. Many (probably most) plug packs and many bench supplies do NOT regulate when fed with current. Some emit magic smoke. Some just go haywire or allow Vout to rise above Vregulated. IF the cct never does this its not a problem. When your intention is to test whether it does this it may be. ....

Comment: One method (which does not do all that's needed is a psu with a diode to "battery" output and a diode from output to a zener of suitable rating. OR if the psu tolerates but does not accept current, a resistor from supply to battery out and a zener at that point

Comment: If you want to measure battery current, a useful sense resistor is. 10A fuse on ground side with 5x20mm fuse giving ~ 11 mOhm or =+/- 11mV per Amp charge or discharge wrt. 0V. Then measure Vbat and Vload using same ground.